# SQL to locate missing records in a single table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL and I need to ensure all my items are located in exactly 5 specific locations. The issue I face is that my items are located in only few of the 5 locations and I need to find the missing ones which i need.

The issue is that the database table has many locations but I need to find only those records where the item is missing in any of the 5 specific locations, the 5 specific locations being Loc1, Loc2, Loc3, Loc4, Loc5

The query Im using is:

```
        WITH Sku (Loc) AS (SELECT 'loc1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
SELECT 'loc2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 'loc3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
SELECT 'loc4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
SELECT 'loc5' FROM DUAL)     
SELECT t.Item, l.Loc FROM Sku l     
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sku t PARTITION BY (t.Item) ON (l.Loc = t.Loc)     
WHERE t.Sku is NULL;
```

But I get an error - Missing Keyword

Below is what I aim to achieve based on the database. Thanks for any advice.

[image: ItemLoc]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text, **NOT** images); and the expected output as text (formatted using markdown, not as images). I expect half the problem is that you have a table in the database named `sku` and have named the sub-query in your query `sku` and that is overshadowing the table - but without the DDL statement for the table we cannot tell that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting from `Sku` twice which, both times is going to select from the locally-defined sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause `Sku` rather than from a table in the database. Change the query to select from the table in the database that contains your data (and if the table in the database is also called `Sku` then call the sub-query in the `WITH` clause something different so it does not shadow the table.

You also want the `WHERE` clause to filter on a column that exists (and is not in the `PARTITION BY` clause) - if you have an `sku` column in your table you could use that but the `ON` clause uses `loc` and you can use that.

```sql
WITH Sku (Loc) AS (
  SELECT 'loc1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'loc2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'loc3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'loc4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'loc5' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.Item, l.Loc
FROM   Sku l     
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY (t.Item)
       ON (l.Loc = t.Loc)     
WHERE  t.loc is NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (item, loc) AS
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item1', 'loc9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'item2', 'loc1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item2', 'loc2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'item2', 'loc3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item2', 'loc4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item2', 'loc6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'item2', 'loc7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
  SELECT 'item3', 'loc9' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| ITEM | LOC |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | loc2 |
| item1 | loc3 |
| item2 | loc5 |
| item3 | loc1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4grUzu94)

Comment: I got it now :) It worked. Thanks a lot MTO. that explanation was clear and concise.  BIG thanks for the effort and time.